# Live database migration MariaDB 10.5 to MySQL 8.0

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb, migration

I need to  move a busy OLTP database from self hosted *MariaDB 10.5* to *Google Cloud SQL for MySQL 8.0* with minimal downtime.

The source is a self managed VM instance in Googles Cloud with replicas, ProxySQL as load balancer, etc. The destination is a Google Cloud SQL. The databse is ~400 GiB on disk and it takes about four hours to load it from a logicak dump.

I used to do this with replication and switchover, but MySQL 8.0 can't read the binary logs from MariaDB.

I would be grateful for any advice on how this move can be implemented with less than 10 minutes of downtime.

Comment: Undoubtedly you'll need more than 10 minutes of downtime unless you're ok with your database having issues after you port it over. This isn't an exact version comparison but close enough to give you a picture of the [differences between database systems](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/incompatibilities-and-feature-differences-between-mariadb-10-7-and-mysql-8-/). Unless you scrub your system closely first and proactively make changes before migrating.

Comment: This is the first I've heard that MySQL can't read binary logs from MariaDB. Out of curiosity, what is the error? Does it have trouble with some SQL syntax, or are there new types of binary log events?

Comment: Test does FEDERATED Engine is available on at least one of your systems. If so then you may attach remote tables and copy your data from or into them like they're local tables. Your DB is large - so copying by chunks seems to be reasonable. Also you may provide referenced rows copying within each chunk.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience recently when trying to move to CloudSQL, I could not get MariaDB (source) to replicate to MySQL 8.0 (replica).

Upon starting replication, as soon as a binary log got replicated from the source, the replica failed with:
`Last_SQL_Error: Relay log read failure: Could not parse relay log event entry. The possible reasons are: the master's binary log is corrupted (you can check this by running 'mysqlbinlog' on the binary log), the slave's relay log is corrupted (you can check this by running 'mysqlbinlog' on the relay log), a network problem, the server was unable to fetch a keyring key required to open an encrypted relay log file, or a bug in the master's or slave's MySQL code. If you want to check the master's binary log or slave's relay log, you will be able to know their names by issuing 'SHOW SLAVE STATUS' on this slave.`

I assume the cause is that the MariaDB and MySQL projects have diverged too much to replicate between eachother with newer versions of MySQL.

The workaround for me was to use multi-stepped replication. Firstly the MariaDB (10.7 in my case) source replicates to a  MySQL 5.7 replica, which replicates to a MySQL 8.0 replica, which then replicates to CloudSQL.

`MariaDB` -> `MySQL 5.7` -> `MySQL 8.0` -> `CloudSQL MySQL 8.0`

To allow my MySQL 8.0 replica to replicate to CloudSQL, I had to set `GTID_MODE=ON` in the server setting, and enable `ASSIGN_GTIDS_TO_ANONYMOUS_TRANSACTIONS=LOCAL` on its replication settings (from the MySQL 5.7 instance). This is because CloudSQL requires GTIDs and does not permit anonymous transactions (binary logs). The replication setting helps to migrate from anonymous transactions to GTIDs, more information can be found [here](https://www.percona.com/blog/useful-gtid-feature-for-migrating-to-mysql-gtid-replication-assign_gtids_to_anonymous_transactions/).

Using this setup we:

- Migrate from MariaDB to MySQL 8.0
- Switch from binary logs to GTID-based replication along the way
- Replicate into CloudSQL

Comment: I followed the advice from OscarVanL adn that works reliable. 
I need some more reputation to upvote this answer, but this is the soution to my problem.